# JButtons connected with JPanel [...]

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a problem and I can't fix it...
If you could take a look at this, I would be grateful.

The problem is, that after pressing buttons, there is no action in JPanel.
Take a look at this:

Here is my code for calling buttons (Pencil, Paintbrush etc.):

```
    if(action.getSource() == newDrawingArea) { drawingArea = new Drawing(); }
    if(action.getSource() == pencilButton) { Drawing.pencil = new Pencil(drawingArea); pencil_condition = true; 
    lines_condition = false; paintbrush_condition = false; Drawing.paintbrush = null; Drawing.lines = null; }
    if(action.getSource() == linesButton) { Drawing.lines = new Lines(drawingArea); lines_condition = true; 
    pencil_condition = false;  paintbrush_condition = false; Drawing.paintbrush = null; Drawing.pencil = null; }
    if(action.getSource() == paintbrushButton) { Drawing.paintbrush = new Paintbrush(drawingArea); paintbrush_condition = true;
    lines_condition = false; pencil_condition = false; Drawing.lines = null; Drawing.pencil = null; }
```

The class, where Objects should create is:

```
public class Drawing extends JPanel {

    public static Pencil pencil;
    public static Lines lines;
    public static Paintbrush paintbrush;

    public Drawing() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pencil = new Pencil(this);
        GUI.pencil_condition = true;

        addMouseListener(pencil);
        addMouseMotionListener(pencil);
        addMouseListener(lines);
        addMouseMotionListener(lines);
        addMouseListener(paintbrush);
        addMouseMotionListener(paintbrush);
        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(GUI.pencil_condition == true) {
            GUI.lines_condition = false; GUI.paintbrush_condition = false; paintbrush = null; lines = null;
        pencil.paintComponent(g);
        }
        if(GUI.lines_condition == true) {
            System.out.println("include lines!");
            GUI.pencil_condition = false;  GUI.paintbrush_condition = false; paintbrush = null; pencil = null;
            lines.paintComponent(g);
        }
        if(GUI.paintbrush_condition == true)
        paintbrush.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have added Boolean type conditions, but it does not work properly.
It also will clear JPanel from previous "drawing" after calling e.g Pencil.

Thanks for your help!

edit:// 
I edited the code a bit, but it still does not work...

How to fix this problem?

edit:// anyone help? :}

Comment: Aside: this `if(GUI.pencil_condition == true) {` is bad coding practice. Just use `if(GUI.pencil_condition) {`

Comment: *"Thanks for your help!"*  Thanks for your question! Wait.. what *is* your question?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - "The problem is, that after pressing buttons, there is no action in JPanel." - I'll admit that *could* be unclear, but given the action snippet at the start, it seems pretty evident.

Comment: That's a problem statement, not a question.  The question might be "Can someone fix it for me?", "Why does this happen?", "How to fix the problem?", "Is this the right design or should I approach it another way"?..  Choose one of those or ask your own, but ask a specific question.  It ain't rocket science.

Comment: Oh, and..  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).